# Multiple Switch-Case statements

Tags: javascript, performance, switch-statement, case

So, i have Switch statement with many cases, e.g.

```
switch(var){
    case 1:
        myfunc();
    break;
    ...
    case 40:
        myanotherfunc();
    break;
}
```

Is separating these cases in several sub-switches a good way to improve perfomance? E.g.

```
    switch(var){
        case 1:
            switch(var2){
                 case 1:
                      myfunc();
                 break;

                 case 2:
                      myfuncfoo();
                 break;
             };
        break;
        ...
        case 5:
            switch(var2){
                 case 1:
                      myfunct();
                 break;

                 case 2:
                      myfuncfoobar();
                 break;
            };
         break;
```

I guess in this case, js won't check all of cases, it will check first several cases, then second several cases, etc.

Comment: It is not possible to write your code that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intrigued I decided to make a very quick test.
It seems there's very little difference performance-wise if the case is random.. (strangely on IE the double switch seems to perform worse compared to chrome.) Smallswitch does have the extra math.floor and dividing of course..

Maybe significant differences are visible as the switch gets much larger, but I'd say on average it would still tend to be down to luck (which cases are being hit, an earlier one or a later one) which is faster.

```
function bigSwitch(value){
    switch(value){
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 8:
            break;
        case 9:
            break;
        case 10:
            break;
        case 11:
            break;
        case 12:
            break;
        case 13:
            break;
        case 14:
            break;
        case 15:
            break;
        case 16:
            break;
        case 17:
            break;
        case 18:
            break;
        case 19:
            break;
        case 20:
            break;    
    }
}

function smallSwitch(value){    
    switch(Math.floor(value/5)+1){
        case 1:
            switch(value%5){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch(value%5){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            switch(value%5){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            switch(value%5){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

var runsToDo = 10000000;
var timer = Date.now();
for(var i=0; i<runsToDo; i++){
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + 1; 
    bigSwitch(value);     
}
console.log("BigSwitch time = ", Date.now() - timer); 

timer = Date.now();
for(var i=0; i<runsToDo; i++){
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + 1; 
    smallSwitch(value); 
}
console.log("smallSwitch time = ", Date.now() - timer);
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/m67uhuxy/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about performance -- that is a feature which changes from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine, but readability wise, it is horrid.

Since JavaScript has such excellent key/value support in objects, and object access optimized to be insanely fast, I have found myself not ever using the switch statement at all any more.

```
var myDoGizmo = {
  "1": {
     "1": func1_1,
     "2": func1_2
   },
  "2": {
     "1": func2_1,
     "2": func2_2
   }
};

// Maybe a guard here if there can possibly be an out-of-range value.    
myDoGizmo[1][1]();
```